# SQL how to store employees holiday requests and remaining days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following requirement (SQL Server):

I need to store all employee leave requests (vacations only) in a table. Also I need to know how many days left (`vacations`) in the period (employee joining date year period).

An employee can request **in advance** days of the next period to be used in the actual period.

Here is schematic of how it should work:

[image]

Each Vacation Period is from Employee Joining Date plus one year.

1. The first period (when employee joins the company) he gets **4** vacations days by default.
2. Then, every period the employee gets 2 days more with a limit of 18 days.

If we see the Period **2011-2012**:

1. The employee has **5** vacations days to use
2. Because it is the first year, there are no previous periods unused days.
3. He got 4 vacation days authorized so, he used **4** days.
4. The remaining days of that period was **1** day, which are accumulative for the next period.

If we see the Period **2012-2013**:

1. The employee now has **7** vacations days to use.
2. He has **1** day unused from previous period.
3. He got 10 vacation days authorized so, he used **10** days.
4. Because he just has **7** days from the actual period plus **1** unused day from the previous, he only has 8 days. But, the company let him take days "in advance" from next period. In this case he request **2** days in advance.
5. The remaining days of the period was **0** days.

Now, if we see the Period **2013-2014**:

1. The employee now has **9** vacations days to use.
2. He has **-2** days requested in advance.
3. He got 6 vacation days authorized so, he used **6** days.
4. Because he has **9** days from the actual period minus **2** days requested in advance from the previous, he only has 7 days.
5. The remaining days left of the period is **1** day.

My actual `employee_holiday` and `employee_holiday_item` tables are:

- `employee_holiday` table will hold all vacations requests
- `employee_holiday_item` table will store non-continuous days in case the employee in the same vacation request he asked for non-continuous days.

`employee_holiday` will hold all holiday requests

[image]

I would like to know if other tables are suggested in order to achieve what I need.

I don't think would be necessary to create an `employee_holiday_period` table for each period because all the information from vacation requests are already in the `employee_holiday` table and I already know from my `employee` table the join date.

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: SQL Server, just updated the question.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag - that is why I asked

Answer (score 0):

To me, your employee_holiday table seems to be more of a log table. If you don't mind I'm going to use different names that I think could be applicable to more than just holiday leave.

You would have a table called `employee_ leaveTime` that would store the type of leave and the number of days left. Then in `employee_leaveTime_log` (which you have named `employee_holiday`) you can log an employee's request for leave (whether that be vacation, sick, etc) as well as any other data you want to keep track of. Then you subtract from the days left for that particular leave type in the other table. With this you can better add time.

I think with this you could user it for more than just vacation time off

Comment: But, the number of days left are related to a period (join date + 1 year).

Comment: By join date, what do you mean?

Comment: when the employee join the company.

Comment: Why not at the beginning of each month add a day to the leave time? Then you do not need to do any calculations to figure out the remaining leave time. It will already be recorded.  As for join date, that should be recorded in employee info or something

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding I have create below script. 
The CTE part will calculate total leave of the employee based on his service in the company. "LeaveTaken" calculates the all the leaves taken by the employee. In the end I have taken the difference of employee's total leave and leave taken by him. If this comes as a negative value that means employee has taken advance leave else the value will be positive.

Pass employee's ID as @UserID .You might have to make few changes in the code, so go through the code before executing.

```
DECLARE @NoYearsOfService INT = 15; --DATEDIFF(Years,DateOfJoining,CurrentYear)
DECLARE @Leavetaken INT;

SELECT @Leavetaken = SUM(Leaves)
    FROM (
                SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DAYS,StartDate,EndDate)) L
                FROM employee_holiday
                WHERE UserID = @UserID

                UNION

                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM employee_holiday_item
         ) temp

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 4 Days,
           4 TotalLeaves,
           1 Years

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  Days + 2,
            CASE WHEN Days < 18 
                THEN TotalLeaves + Days + 2
                ELSE TotalLeaves + 18 END,
           Years + 1
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE Years < @NoYearsOfService
)

SELECT TotalLeaves - @Leavetaken
FROM CTE
WHERE Years = @NoYearsOfService
```